# Comparing photocatalytic kinetic and reaction rate of PPCPs removal in water treatment

Tags: reaction-mechanism

Can anyone explain to me what is the meaning the kinetic term in the question and how does it relate to reaction rate constant, k ? I have been reading a lot of articles but was unable to get an understanding on the kinetic term. In addition, is there a difference between degradation of PPCPs by photocatalyst and photo-oxidation ? Since photocatalyst process has oxidation as well, I am kinda confused between those two. Any help provided with be appreciated.